# Ideal status in Microsoft Teams

Tags: work-environment

This is a generic question. I chose MS Teams as an example. Basically any such application that has these particular **statuses** as options.

I am not sure about the reason behind the **downvotes**. Perhaps people think it is **"opinion-based"**.

If that is the case, then ironically I stumbled upon these suggested questions which also sound like opinionated ones, but have received a different reaction :

[image: seemingly-opinion-based-questions]

## Tl;dr

What should be the ideal **status** if a person is working on a project and at the same time open to support queries.

## Detailed

If a member of a software engineering team(like a DevOps team) where the team is responsible for working on stories as well as supporting the developers via Teams chat/Emails/Quick calls/ KT sessions, etc, then in such cases what should the team members ideally set their status to?

Should it be always set to **available** except for meetings/calls and that the status **busy** should be only used if we really want to have that extra focus(again how do we define focus) ?

As per the [official documentation of Microsoft Teams](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-your-status-in-teams-ce36ed14-6bc9-4775-a33e-6629ba4ff78e),

> **Available** is when you’re active in Teams and don’t have anything in your calendar (no meetings or calls, for example). Note that Teams will automatically set your status from Available to Away when you lock your computer or when it enters idle or sleep mode. On mobile, this will happen when the Teams app is in the background.

> **Busy** is when you want to focus on something, and you do want notifications to pop up.  If you’re in a meeting or call, Teams will automatically change your status to In a meeting or In a call (Busy) when not set to Do not disturb.

> **Do not disturb** is when you want to focus or present your screen and don’t want notifications to pop up.

> **Be right back** is when you want to say you’re temporarily away. It’s never set automatically.

> **Appear away** is when you need to work without responding right away.

> **Appear offline** is when you want to indicate that you're not signed in to Teams, so will not be responding until you're back online. You'll still receive notifications if anyone messages you.

Is it right for those DevOps team members to leave their status set to **Avalaible**, just because they do not have any calls/meetings in their calendar. What if they are working on some stories ? Working on any story anyways requires focus.

Also, what does **focus** specifically mean in case of the status **busy**. What if a job responsibility demands one to remain focused all the time?

When is **Appear away** a good fit and should this option even exist in an workplace setup ?

## What I did until today:

I prefer having the **busy** option always on.
However I was recently advised by one senior member not to always leave it busy.

I gently asked for any specific reason and but the answer wasn't convincing.

The reason was given was just about the possibility of people misunderstanding my **busy** status as something meaning **"Please do not disturb me. I am pretty busy now"**.

I believe people should be sensible enough to know when to ask an when not to disturb. IMHO having status set to busy is an indicator to others that my time is precious and you have to be respectful of that.

Comment: Don't overthink that. Most people (at least in my organization) ignore the status completely. If you want to use it for something meaningful, you should create a company policy about it. This is something every organization and every team handles in its own way.

Comment: `"if a person is working on a project"` ...as opposed to not doing any work at all?

Comment: @jwsc I added few details at the end. I am good if it is organization, which I don't believe is the case here. This was something suggested by a senior and with due respect I never felt satisfied with response.

Comment: @musefan Its like a DevOps engineer who is responsible for developing and maintaining the developer ecosystem and at the same time open to support queries from other  developers. So it like, always involved into something on any working day(there might be exceptions on some days in which case status available seems to be a good fit ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you always set your status to the same thing (whether that thing is busy, available, or whatever) then you remove the ability for your status to convey any information at all. It doesn't really matter whether you think people should know they can interrupt even when you're busy, or that people should check if you have time even when you're available. You're just taking a signal that could give people information and wasting it by always setting it to the exact same thing.

So stop doing that. Pick a rule of some kind and use it. People generally expect that Available means I can just talk to you: "hey, do you remember where the xyz is?" or "are you going out for lunch today? Bunch of us are considering tacos if you're interested", Busy means I can interrupt for things that are both quick and urgent: "is Steve with you I really need him to call me NOW", and Do Not Disturb means if fire and police departments are not involved, leave me alone.

You can vary from these rules if you like, and that will be slightly less rude than always having the same status, but I don't see any good reason to do so. Go ahead and use Do Not Disturb whenever **you** feel like your focus would be lost if someone pinged you at that moment, and it's important not to lose it. Don't overuse DND or it will become, like your current always-busy, a nonsignal that people ignore.

As for "Appear Away", it's a form of DND that probably shouldn't be used. People might think you're never at your desk. But don't spend energy wondering why it's there, just don't use it yourself.

Comment: //You're just taking a signal that could give people information and wasting it by always setting it to the exact same thing// For me, this line sums it up quite nicely.

Answer (score 3):

> What should be the ideal status if a person is working on a project and at the same time open to support queries.

This really depends on your company culture.  Going further, it also is very dependent on individual behavior.

While some people will respect the status settings, I have encountered many who ignore it completely.

Just set the status to whatever you feel is correct for your availability.  If someone sends you a message when they should not, ignore it until you are available to reply.  If they later question why it took you so long to reply, you can let them know that you were busy and your status reflected this as well.  Hopefully, that will get them to think about checking the status before sending their message in the future.

Comment: Heck, at my old company I used to update my status as a long running story told 100 characters per day. The only real use people had were OOO or sick messages, aside from that people pretty much ignored statuses.